# The difference between a bad answer and a non-answer

Tags: discussion, policy, deleted-answers, answer-quality

It seems to me (I may be wrong) that there is some sort of confusion or disagreement (recently) about what makes something "not an answer" as opposed to a bad answer. I think it is important that there be some kind of sitewide understanding/agreement about what constitutes a non-answer. What follows is my understanding; anyone can feel free to respond with an alternate understanding:

- Something which *is* an answer should not be deleted as "not-an-answer".
- Something is an answer if it directly addresses the question. If a question is made up of multiple questions or multiple premises, a partial answer can address a distinct part of the question.
- If a post does not directly address the question then it is not an answer. It is not an answer even if every word in it is true and even if it cites authoritative sources for what it says. If the information is *related* to the question but does not *address* the question then it is not an answer, and in certain cases it should be posted as a comment instead.
- If a post *does* directly address the question then it is an answer. It is an answer even if every word in it is not true and even if it cites no sources.
- If a post is unclear, unintelligible, written in a different language, etc. then it is probably not an answer.
- Something which could technically be an answer (i.e. it addresses the question) can still be deleted for other reasons (e.g. spam, abusive, etc.)
- If something is a bad answer (i.e. it addresses the question but it is not correct) it should be downvoted. (Enough downvotes deletes the question automatically?)
- If something is *not* an answer it can also be downvoted (primarily by those who don't have the power to delete it).

In short, I think that bad answers should not be deleted as non-answers, and non-answers should not be not deleted just because they contain good information.

I think the above is more or less supported by the explanation given for the "not-an-answer" flag which states:

> This was posted as an answer, but it does not attempt to answer the
>   question. It should possibly be an edit, a comment, another question,
>   or deleted altogether.

If anyone thinks that any or all of the above is wrong, or if anyone disagrees with any or all of my understanding, please post an answer outlining your understanding of the parameters of "not-an-answer".

If you think this is not an issue at all, or has already been properly addressed, feel free to ignore or downvote this question.

Comment: Related: https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4637/dealing-with-incorrect-answers

Comment: Related: https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4736/why-did-my-answer-disappear#comment14776_4737

Comment: See also https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2179/170

Comment: And: https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1912/are-answer-posts-of-the-form-your-answer-isnt-okay?rq=1

Comment: Furthermore: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/225370/147191

Comment: How do you relate to/understand 'very low quality' flags for deletion?

Comment: @רבותמחשבות Where is that flag? I don't see it under the choices when flagging an answer.

Comment: Don't seem to see it when I flag answers anymore, but it definitely exists/existed.  You can see the queue for it in Review, and it is all over the place at Meta.SE. (e.g [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/181165/can-flags-send-a-post-into-the-low-quality-posts-review-queue/190639#190639))

Comment: @רבותמחשבות I don't know. If it doesn't exist now, then I guess we don't need to relate to it. On the other hand, if it does exist, the very fact that there is a separate flag for "very low quality" implies that a very low quality answer is not "not an answer".  I did mention in the post that even something which does not qualify as "not an answer" could still be deleted for another reason.

Comment: @alex very weird.  I regularly flag bad answers with that flag, as can be seen in my flagging history ( don't think you can see it).  Most recently, I flagged this as low quality: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/94390/how-do-i-know-my-unanswered-questions-will-be-revealed-to-me-when-i-die/94398#94398  See my comment where I wrote that explicitly.  So not sure where it suddenly went

Comment: @רבותמחשבות I can't see your flagging history but I can see the history of your actions from the review queues.

Comment: related: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/264474/reorganise-the-lq-fp-and-la-queues-to-have-one-queue-about-improving-and-guidin

Comment: Does VLQ only show up for negatively voted posts?

Comment: @doubleaa tried that too -still didn't come up.

Comment: @DoubleAA VLQ only shows on [recent (1 week) non-positive answers](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/search?tab=newest&q=is%3aa%20score%3a..0%20created%3a7d..).